# How to define consult faces generically for minibuffer highlighting that fits with your selected theme?

Tags: fonts, themes, highlighting, text-properties, consult

### Background

I'm experimenting with different themes to see which one I prefer. I'm giving a theme time to soak, so to speak, by using it for a few weeks. At the moment I'm trying the paganini theme.

### Consult results issue to solve:

#### 1. Improved line highlighting

As can be seen in the attached image, highlighting *works* for some consult results. In the image you can see `*Colors*` currently highlighted in the minibuffer in an orange color whereas the alternative buffers are in white.

In the editor itself you can see line 56 with a faint background color also to indicate the current line the cursor is on.

What property should be set to do the same whilst cycling through results in the minibuffer with the up/down arrows or `C-p` and `C-n`?

#### 2. File results highlighting confused with list color

If instead of switching to an active buffer I `C-n` (or down-arrow) to a historically visited file like `~/Code/ldeck/zio/zio-hello/build.sbt` I see no highlighting at all for those results. i.e., all results under `--- File ---` do not change color nor change background color to indicate the current selection.

It turns out that `defface consult-file` inherits by default from `font-lock-function-name-face`. The `defface consult-file` has the description: "Face used to highlight files in `consult-buffer'."

But it appears in this case that that setting is being used for listed files, not highlighted files.

So I can `(set-face-attribute 'consult-file nil :inherit nil)` to fix that for the moment and then those historical files highlight in the same way that the open buffers do.

If I, however, I customise the color of `consult-file` to use any foreground color, no highlighting appears at all when up/downing through possible results.

Is there another property I'm missing that would allow this to be customised but also honour highlighting?

How would I define a background color to highlight the minibuffer line currently selected?

[image: consult switch buffer results]

Comment: Could you try and customize `vertico-current` also?

Comment: Thanks for the hint @SwarnenduBiswas. Do you have any particular lisp in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to set the highlight background face so that while iterating through the results, the current item is background highlighted.

That way, whatever the foreground color happens to be, the current item is distinguished from the others via its highlighted background.

For example, taking the pictured "5/197  Switch to:" color as roughly `#3498db`, and using a color picker to darken it (experimenting along the way by executing the below set-face-attribute command) you can arrive at something that fits the theme and then plug it into your emacs config.

```lisp
...
(global-hl-line-mode 1)
(set-face-attribute 'highlight nil :background "#294F6E")
```